# Что такое модель?

Tags: java, c#, orm, проектирование, dao

Довольно часто встречается понятие модели в терминах, например, MVC или ORM. Но что это такое ?

Скажем, у нас есть таблица `users`. Раньше мне казалось, что моделью будет являться конкретная строка этой таблица, которая обернута в класс `User`. После чтения про паттерн `DAO`, я немного запутался. Тут класс User - это бин (`bean`), а модель - это вся таблица целиком.

Правильно ли я понимаю ?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/321050/ - вот имхо неплохое объяснение, что такое модель.

Comment: И то, и другое. Модель — это часть кода, _моделирующая_ предметную область.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Модель, в случае паттернов `MVP`, `MVC` — это слой, который представляет логику Вашего проекта, абстрагирован от любых деталей UI, задач преобразования данных и т.д.

---

Чтобы было понятнее, пример (с использование паттерна `MVP`). Имеется калькулятор с GUI и три класса реализации:

`View.java` — будет отвечать за отображение (создает окошко, выставляет поля и т.д.)
`Presenter.java` — будет отвечать за перенаправление кликов и полученных данных в `Model.java`.

`Model.java` — считает полученные данные и возвращает в `Presenter`.

---

Как это работает:

Пользователь вводит числа 2, 10 и нажимает "Добавить". `View` отдает данные `Presenter`, он их преобразовывает (складывает в объект `MathAction`) и отдает в `Model`. `Model` считает и возвращает результат. `Presenter`, который получает результат в виде объекта, достает из него число с результатом и указывает `View` его отобразить.